# Lottery Probability Question

Tags: probability, lotteries

As PowerBall has has 26 power balls, so I assume the odd to win the lowest prize (having the right power ball) should be 1 in 26, however the site says 1 in 38.32
Also MegaMillions game has 25 mega balls, so I assume the odds for lowest prize is 1 in 25, but it's 1 in 37 on the website.

What am I missing here??

Edited

For powerball game, the player chooses five numbers 1 to 69 and one number 1 to 26 to be Power ball. For the lowest prize when you have the right power ball regardless of other 5 balls, I don't find any relation to calculate the odds for other balls. That's why I see something is wrong and I posted the question. and It should simply be 1 in 26, but their website says 1 in 38.32

Comment: You miss editing your posting to summarize the rules of the corresponding games so that the reviewers don't have to wade through them.

Comment: Also, I don't see your work.  Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: On "*the website.*"  What website?  What exact phrasing is being used?  Are you taking into account the possibility of sharing the prize with someone else if they also win?  Are you sure the rules you believe to be in place are the rules that are being followed by the website you allude to?  Are you aware of the distinction between representing information as odds versus representing information as probability?  I expect this to just be you not reading things properly.

Comment: Also a probable point of confusion, is in whether you are considering "winning the lowest prize" as winning the lowest **and not anything better**.  Having matched the powerball *and not* matched any others is not the same thing as having matched the powerball *and* matching any others which is further different than having matched the powerball without worrying about anything else.  The odds of $1$ in $37$ sound like matching the powerball but missing having matched anything else, which is of course worse odds than just matching the powerball without caring about anything else.

Comment: As a general PSA, just in case you are asking this because of your interest in playing yourself... gambling as a form of entertainment is perhaps okay... but you should *not* be gambling for the purposes of attempting to increase your wealth and is not a reliable investment strategy.  There is a reason why these lotteries are often referred to as a "stupidity tax."  The expected returns are always negative.

Comment: @JMoravitz The website mentioned odds and all other formal websites have same rations. However I understand that odds should be even lesser than probabilities while the opposite is here. I updated the question for the game's rule if it has anything to do with winning the lowest prize. I play lottery sometimes but I'm just wondering why the odd is not 1 in 25? Anyway the prize is just $2 so it's no one's goal :D

Comment: @JMoravitz I got it .. "the lowest and not anything better" that's all about. Thanks for your comments

Comment: A probability of $\dfrac{1}{26}$ can be written as a probability of "1 in 26" or as odds of "1 **to** 25 (*in favor*)" or as odds of "25 *to* 1 against."  They are arguably not using the word "odds" correctly here but are instead using it for its colloquial meaning as a stand-in for the word probability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $69$ normal balls and $26$ power balls...

The probability to match the powerball **and possibly match more than just that** will indeed be $\dfrac{1}{26}$

The probability to match the powerball and *not* match **anything else**... well, there are $\binom{69}{5}$ different selections of $5$ different numbers possible.  $\binom{64}{5}$ of those selections happen to miss all five of the correct numbers.  The probability of missing all normal numbers but matching the powerball will be $\dfrac{\binom{64}{5}}{26\cdot\binom{69}{5}}$ which is approximately $\dfrac{1}{38.3239\dots}$

You are reading the information incorrectly.